# "Could not open input file" crons error

Tags: cron

There are a few other questions on Stack Overflow about this and I do understand that, but none of them are giving me an idea of why im getting the `"Could not open input file"`.

I have it setup so I get an email everytime a crons runs (im using cPanal to set the crons) but all I get is:

`Could not open input file: /home/methodjs/classified/emailNotifications.php`

Because is the first time i'm using crons jobs I have no idea what this means or how fix it.

My command line is:

`/usr/local/bin/php $HOME/classified/emailNotifications.php`

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help. By the way, i'm sure thats the right path to PHP because thats what I got from my host.

Comment: Q: Is your $HOME "/home/methodjs"?  Q: Do you have command line (e.g. ssh, or a desktop session) to this host?

Comment: @paulsm4 A: Yes, it is. A: No, I do not. Or, not that I know of.

Comment: Yea... if you could log in and test it from the command line, that might give you some clues.

Comment: @pedz Im not sure what you mean from the command line. Is that a tool in cPanel?...I dont think I have a command line to my host. Not sure what that is.

Comment: Q: What do you mean by 'command line'?  A: See if your provider offers "shell access".  Without "ssh", a terminal window or some kind of "command line access", your options for doing just about *anything* useful are extremely limited.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 My provider does not offer shell access. It doesn't seem like I have any command line access.

Comment: In a word ... then perhaps you need another provider?

Answer (score 0):

ensure file is located here:

```
 /home/methodjs/classified/emailNotifications.php
```

try to execute from commandline:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/methodjs/classified/emailNotifications.php
```

what appears?

ensure your php file has execution rights

```
chmod 755 /home/methodjs/classified/emailNotifications.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears either file is not present at given path or proper permission are not set for file. It can be checked by navigating to path and ll for checking permission.

Answer (score 0):

All,

This problem started occurring on all my 20 Kubuntu machines after an update from Ubuntu!  Since Ubuntu is Debian based not sure if Debian or Ubuntu is to blame, so investigating!

Debian users, if this is also impacting you please reply so we can investigate further!

Cheers!